# Between operator does not return any value if the dates are equal

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called `Products` inside that table I have three records:

```
ID | Price | Date
 1   20.0    2018-04-03 18:30:00
 2   30.00   2018-04-03 18:30:00
 3   30.00   2018-04-04 18:30:00
```

I want return all the records that have as `Date` an intervall of `2018-04-01` (start date), and `2018-04-03` (end date). The final result should be (id): `1,2`.

My query have this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2018-04-03' AND '2018-04-03'
```

When I execute it inside `DB Browser for Slite` utility I get this message:

> 0 rows returned in 0ms from: SELECT * FROM Products WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2018-04-03' AND '2018-04-03'

But if I edit the query in:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2018-04-03' AND '2018-04-04'
```

I correctly get the records with ids: `2, 3`.

Is this a bug or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date without a time is exactly midnight.  If you want data on that date, I would recommend:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
WHERE datetime >= '2018-04-03' AND datetime < '2018-04-04';
```

This will return all times on 2018-04-03.

I strongly discourage using `between` with date/times.  It is just confusing, because of the time component.  Aaron Bertrand has a rather extensive blog on this subject, [What Do The Devil and Between Have In Common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Although the blog is for SQL Server, it applies to other databases as well.

Comment: An additional problem is that SQLite does not really have a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type. That column could hold values like `2018-04-03`, `2018-04-03 18:19:20`, `04-03-2018 06:19:20 PM`,  `4/3/18` or even `foobar`

Comment: I banged my head for hours on this problem, thank you very much, I will read the article on the blog, I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Gordon's answer, which is what should probably be used in production, *would* be to use `BETWEEN`, but with an appropriate range:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products 
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2018-04-03 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-03 23:59:59';
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive on both ends, so the above would include the third of April 2018, from midnight to one second before midnight of the same day.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE cast(datetime as date) BETWEEN '2018-04-03' AND '2018-04-03'
```

Comment: SQLite has no date type, hence casting makes no sense.